# How can I permanently add a path to my bash profile?

Tags: unix, path, .bash-profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set PATH and other environment variables?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables)

I would like to put the path of a binary in my bash profile which is not present in the usual location like `/usr/bin` or `/sbin`. For example, if the following is the path of the binary:

```
/path/to/bin
```

How would I put this path permanently in my bash profile so that every time I login I don't need to specify the path of the binary?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set PATH and other environment variables?](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables), especially [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/how-do-i-set-path-and-other-environment-variables/284361#284361) which would explain the syntax.

Answer (score 5):

You should edit your `~/.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, and add something like:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bin
```

Comment: I did the same  but i am not seeing the path after running the command **$PATH** from terminal. Do i need to do restart? Is there any command for it?

Comment: You need to start a new shell.  To have an immediate effect, you can also type `source ~/.bashrc` (or simply `. ~/.bashrc`).

Comment: type `source ~/.bashrc` to get it to update the PATH immediately.

Comment: the bash profile is only read when you login to that terminal. Start a new terminal, and `echo $PATH` should be correct.

Comment: I am getting following error **bash: export: `=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/path/to/bin not a valid identifier**.Even **$PATH** does not show the path i have added.

Comment: @thetna: Please double-check that the code you've added is *exactly* as I've typed above.  In particular, check the `$`!

Comment: @Oli I checked it many times.Got the same.

Comment: @thetna: Then I don't know.  The code above is valid!

Comment: Make sure this bit **->PATH=$PATH:/path/to/bin<-** has no spaces in it.

Comment: Or better: Edit your question to show (paste) the contents of your .bashrc (or at least a few lines containing your edit).